# Sharing internet from a laptop to other laptop

Tags: windows-7, windows, internet, proxy

Here is my scenario. I have two laptops with me A and B. A is getting wireless internet connection from a Router. B(no wireless) is connected to A via LAN (I can ping two laptops from each other and this is working). My goal is to connect internet in B from A via proxy. Right now I can only seeing LAN connection but internet connectivity is not there in B. Here is the screenshot of B:
[image]

What settings I need to make in A computer so that B can access the Internet via A via proxy.

Comment: I know it can be done, since I've done it (going the other direction, IIRC).  But I don't remember the details, and I recall that UNdoing it was tricky -- I lost my wifi for a couple of days until I figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a Bridge connection would be the simplest option.

Simply go to Network Connections (there should be an option in the Network and Sharing Center for this). Select the two connections - Lan and Wifi in your case, then right-click on one of the selected ones. The option "Bridge connections" should appear. Just click it and windows does the rest.

(Note: I still use Windows XP more than Windows 7, so some of the terms, for instance "Bridge connections", may be something different, just look for something similar).

Answer (score 0):

I've done this before. I believe you have to bridge your LAN connection with your wireless connection so your LAN connection can utilize the wifi...

Answer (score 0):

This guide from Help Desk Geek is concise and will help you bridge the connection between your WiFi and ethernet networks:

http://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-7/bridge-network-connections-in-windows-7/